# How to set a variable to null instead of catching a NullReferenceException, when a database field is empty/null?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I get a list of all users in my database with the following code:

```
IEnumerable<Firma> firmaer = db.Firma.ToList();
```

I try to map each user to a ViewModel that looks like this:

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    public String CVR_Nummer { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastActivityDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public String FirmaNavn { get; set; }

}
```

When the field firma_navn in the datbase is empty, i get a NullReferenceException

```
model.FirmaNavn = firmaer.Where(x => x.CVR_nummer == user.UserName).FirstOrDefault().firma_navn ?? "Missing";
```

It throws a NullReferenceException.

I can catch this exception, but i have heard somewhere that catching exceptions is kind of heavy.

What i would like to do is make

```
model.FirmaNavn = "Missing";
```

If the field is empty in the database.

Is this possible without catching the exception, or am i wrong about catching exception is heavy?

**EDIT**

This is how the method looks like now (after help):

```
public List<UserViewModel> MapUserViewModel(MembershipUserCollection users)
        {
            List<UserViewModel> userviewmodel = new List<UserViewModel>();

            IEnumerable<Firma> firmaer = db.Firma.ToList();

            foreach (MembershipUser user in users)
            {
                UserViewModel model = new UserViewModel();
                model.CVR_Nummer = user.UserName;
                model.CreationDate = user.CreationDate;
                model.LastActivityDate = user.LastActivityDate;

                var firma = firmaer.Where(x => x.CVR_nummer == user.UserName).FirstOrDefault();

                if (firma != null)
                {
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(firma.firma_navn))
                        model.FirmaNavn = "Missing";
else
model.FirmaNavn = firma.firma_navn;
                }

                /*if (firmaer != null)
                {
                    var firma = firmaer.Where(x => x.CVR_nummer == user.UserName).FirstOrDefault();
                    model.FirmaNavn = firma.firma_navn ?? "Mangler";   
                }
                */
                userviewmodel.Add(model);
            }
            return userviewmodel;
        }
```

Now works. Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked in the debugger to see exactly what's `null`?

Comment: Odd - I wouldn't have thought that it would cause a `NullReferenceException` in the line you've posted.

Comment: The error here is not the "firma_navn" field being null - it is because zero rows are returned, and the *object* (from FirstOrDefault) is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not wrong about catching exceptions being "heavy" - and they should really only be used for the truly exceptional circumstances.

If `firma_navn` is likely to be `null` then it's not an exceptional circumstance, so you should code accordingly:

```
if (firmaer != null)
{
    var model = firmaer.Where(x => x.CVR_nummer == user.UserName).FirstOrDefault();
    if (model != null)
    {
        model.FirmaNavn = model.firma_navn ?? "Missing";
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using your code and i still get an Object reference not set to an instance of an object error, on model.FirmaNavn = model.firma_navn ?? "Missing";

Comment: So if you put a debug on if (model != null), what is it then?

Comment: I was doing it wrong. It works now. I like the solution. Less code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check whether your LINQ statement returns an entity to avoid the `NullReferenceException`.

```
var firma= firmaer.Where(x => x.CVR_nummer == user.UserName).FirstOrDefault();

if (firma != null)
{
    model.FirmaNavn = 
        string.IsNullOrEmpty(firma.firma_navn) ? "Missing" : firma.firma_navn;

   // do stuff with model
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  var test= = firmaer.Where(x => x.CVR_nummeruser.UserName).FirstOrDefault();

  if(test == null)
  {
  model.FirmaNavn = "Missing";
  }
  else
  {
    model.FirmaNavn =(string)test;
  }
```

See also:

[The C# ?? null coalescing operator (and using it with LINQ)](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/09/20/the-new-c-null-coalescing-operator-and-using-it-with-linq.aspx)

Regards

Answer (score 0):

```
// seems the line firmaer.Where(x => x.CVR_nummer == user.UserName).FirstOrDefault() is returning null or no match found

// you can try this. i guess FirmA is the model class  
model.FirmaNavn = (firmaer.Where(x => x.CVR_nummer == user.UserName).FirstOrDefault() ?? new FirmA(){firma_navn="Missing"}).firma_navn;
```